# Bluetooth manager not connecting to devices after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, connection, 23.04

Ever since upgrading from Ubuntu 22.10 to Ubuntu 23.04, bluetooth doesn't appear to connect any more. If I try a cold connect to my portable speaker, it connects for one second, then disconnects.  If I pair and trust my device, it won't connect automatically. When connecting manually I get the following error:

```
Connection Failed: br-connection-profile-unavailable.
```

Also `bluetooth service status` shows:

```
root@:/home/# service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-04-30 16:58:12 AEST; 1min 41s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 680 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18371)
     Memory: 2.1M
        CPU: 35ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─680 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: Bluetooth daemon 5.66
Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: Starting SDP server
Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: profiles/audio/vcp.c:vcp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init vcp plugin
Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: profiles/audio/mcp.c:mcp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init mcp plugin
Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: profiles/audio/bap.c:bap_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init bap plugin
Apr 30 16:58:12  bluetoothd[680]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Apr 30 16:58:12  systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
```

I've tried rebooting, various fixes to `/etc/bluetooth.main.cnf` and reinstalling Ubuntu, but nothing seems to help. I assume this is just an issue with the early release of 23.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

this worked for me

```
sudo apt-get purge bluez-alsa-utils pulseaudio-module-bluetooth ; sudo apt-get install --reinstall libspa-0.2-bluetooth && systemctl reboot
```

device (lsusb)

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you

Comment: Thank you! Also worked on Debian, after an upgrade that installed pipewire.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem and it appeared that bluez-alsa-utils was not installed in the system. Installing it fixed the issue for me :

```
sudo apt install bluez-alsa-utils
```

then executing the line of commands of schwarzheit worked, thanks !

Comment: Note that the line that @schwarzheit posted removes `bluez-alsa-utils` (and `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`). The package that is needed to be installed is apparently: `libspa-0.2-bluetooth`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm

sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd

reboot
```

Credit goes to @jeremy31:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486421&p=14142312#post14142312

Comment: After a month, I decided to try 23.04 again. 

Tried the suggestion above to get a file from winterheart but this has no effect. service bluetooth status still showing the same plugin errors.  I can detect and register my bluetooth device but it will only connect for a few seconds, then disconnect again. There definitely seems to be a problem with this version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several suggestions, all to no avail. I try to avoid solutions that entail the command prompt unless it only takes two or three commands, so I searched all options in de Bluetooth manager GUI first. Lo and behold, I unchecked the box for 'Hide unnamed devices' under the 'view' option in the menu. And now it shows all devices. Mind you, I was rather sloppy with my trial and error procedures so it may be that one of the earlier applied solutions may have done the trick after a few reboots but I thought it was worth mentioning.